# How to do a fast and safe sync on perforce?

Tags: perforce, synchronization

If you do a `sync` in perforce it can happen, very often, to do nothing even if it should. If you do a forced sync (`sync -f`) it will definitely sync all the files from the server blindly and this is unacceptable if you have a big project.

The question is how can you do a fast sync?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key part to your question is "even if it should". Without fail, in all my (too) many years of experience with Perforce, users who revert to forced syncs habitually, because a normal sync does not do what they expect, are not using Perforce correctly.

You must let Perforce manage your hard disk for you - the server knows which versions of which files you have, and so a normal sync just gets what it needs. If it fails, then that is almost without exception a sign that the user is modifying, deleting, adding, renaming files outside of Perforce (e.g. in Explorer).

Sometimes you may get a system funny (i.e. PC fault, ) that causes this, so it is not necessarily the users fault. But these are very rare - hence my "habitually" qualifier above.

If you think, hand on heart, that you are not doing anything out of the ordinary, then start to look at what other processes could be tweaking these files. E.g. does you build system do something odd, and try to modify files as it builds? Do you have an open network share that perhaps someone else is inadvertently poking? Do you have a backup system that is interfering?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perforce associates which versions of which files you have with your each client spec. This info is kept on the server with each client spec - in what it calls its "have list". Shared clients are not typical user practice. They are allowed by Perforce to enable particular usage scenarios. But if you are working on different machines, then that is handled by having a client spec per machine. It's exactly what they were designed for.

Comment: Let's say you have a build farm - do you want to create a workspace(clientspec) for each computer in the farm?

Comment: Yes, a client spec per machine would be advisable in most circumstances. You can automate their creation, however, so it's not as painful as you may think.

Comment: Greg, can you provide some hints on this? I would like to find a way of following your suggestion  but using an existing clientspec as a template and if someone is updating the original clientspec it script will update the clientspec generated.

Comment: Most scripting can be performed easily with the command line p4 client. You can pipe text in, or, in the case of p4 client, the -t option allows you to provide a template. Try p4 help client for a first look. There are also API's to Perforce (Python, .net etc) - see Perforce website.
For your last requirement, you can add a trigger to Perforce that will invoke a script/command if a client spec is changed. You could use this to regenerate the others - but think about whether you need this to happen immediately, or if you would be better served with an explicit "Publish" option.

Comment: another technique that works relatively well is to mark the client spec as read-write and perform a reconcile (can be scripted) that will automatically mark for edit/add/delete changes done locally.  this way you can perform changes as you normally would (through explorer for example) and still be within P4's secret garden.   Note that you must ensure that all generated files are put in a folder OUTSIDE of the client-spec 's root otherwise you will end up checking in a lot of stuff you may not want there.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by the other answers, you need to create a separate client (workspace) for every "instance" of a directory tree synced from the depot.

If you want to force-sync only those files that have changed from the depot:

```
p4 diff -se ... | p4 -x - sync -f
p4 diff -sd ... | p4 -x - sync -f
```

Warning: that will overwrite any locally changed files (in the current directory and subdirectories).

If instead you edited some files and forgot to open them for edit first, you can do this:

```
p4 diff -se ... | p4 -x - edit
```

which will open for edit any file that's different from the depot.

And this:

```
p4 diff -sd ... | p4 -x - delete
```

will open for delete any file that was locally deleted.

Answer (score 4):

If you create an inconsistency, where perforce looses track of what is going on in your workspace, you should use the "Reconcile offline work..." function (in P4V).

This will run a folder diff and tell you what options you have to resolve the inconsistencies.

In general, make sure that you always check out files explicitly through perforce (open for edit). This feels strange if you are used to other systems.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not aiming to use the visual client for this. For the same project I sync files from 6 different perforce servers so only a batch solution is acceptable - I don't want to repeat the process manually.

Comment: @sorin: Did you ever find out an acceptable solution? I'm running into something similar when attempting to automate builds. I don't want to have to force sync every time, since that takes ~2h.

Comment: Sorry but I do speak perforce anymore. My last experience with them was almost 5 years ago. There is only one future for them, one similar to blackberry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the command you're looking for is p4 clean.

From: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_clean.html

"Files present in the workspace, but missing from the depot are deleted from the workspace.
Files present in the depot, but missing from your workspace. The version of the files that have been synced from the depot are added to your workspace.
Files modified in your workspace that have not been checked in are restored to the last version synced from the depot."

Comment: P4 Clean will definitively do the job but on very big project it is extremely slow (amounts to do a reconcile with automated handling of cases found in favour of server).  The best case for the OP is to perform file operations though perforce (deletes, move, edits etc).  The occasional check should still be performed to see if nothing slipped through the cracks though.